# Qiery tuning and Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, database-performance

How can i optimize the query below? Target time is about one second. I guess I have to rejoin it in another way, but i can't figure out how. The total number of rows after tuning should be 10 572 145 848. Thank you.

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
INNER JOIN Production.TransactionHistory h on sod.ProductID = h.ProductID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh on sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader hsoh on h.ReferenceOrderID = hsoh.SalesOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason sr on soh.SalesOrderID = sr.SalesOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesReason r on sr.SalesReasonID = r.SalesReasonID
```

Comment: A query plan would be a good start, but this is probably not going to get much faster, as I suspect even with indexes, best you'll get is a scan. There's not even a `WHERE` to help reduce the rows for a seek.

Comment: I suspect some of the tables are not relevant. But without knowing what you are counting, it is impossible to be certain.

Comment: DB AdventureWorks2008Default

Comment: Why do you want it to execute in a second? AdventureWorks is just a demo database, so why does it matter if this count takes a couple of seconds (executes in 4 seconds on my PC with AdventureWorks2016).

Comment: Without DDL or an execution plan it's impossible to give a solid answer. That said, if you can get away with turning those LEFT joins into INNER JOINS you can turn your query into an indexed view. This would give you an answer in 0.00 Seconds but there would be a small performance ding when adding/updating/deleting rows from any of the tables referenced in the query. Based on your DDL, data and workflow - this could be a great option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subqueries.

First one: Select **counter_column** with function `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT_BIG(*)` (this column will aggregate number of rows per every **SalesOrderID**), and **SalesOrderID**.

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS counter_column, sod.SalesOrderID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
INNER JOIN Production.TransactionHistory h
  ON sod.ProductID = h.ProductID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh 
  ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader hsoh 
  ON h.ReferenceOrderID = hsoh.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY sod.SalesOrderID
```

Second one left joining last two tables

```
SELECT sr.SalesOrderID, sr.SalesReasonID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason sr 
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesReason r
  ON sr.SalesReasonID = r.SalesReasonID
```

Also you need to left join this two tables by SalesOrderID and find sum of counter_column of this joined tables.

The query optimized little bit by grouping and counting all rows in first subquery.